# Laravel latin5_turkish_ci Collation Issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

1. My mariaDB database has `latin5_turkish_ci` collation.
2. My page meta has `charset=iso-8859-9`
3. using laravel 4.2
4. Values look properly on the page, when i get them from database.
5. **Problem:** Values don't seem as proper characters on the database, when i post them from the form. They seem like **Ã¼Ã¼Ã¼Ã¼**.

**app/config/database.php :**

```
'charset'   => 'latin5',
'collation' => 'latin5_turkish_ci',
```

**head.blade.php**

```
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=x-mac-turkish" />
```

How can i submit values into database in proper characters ?

Comment: Use only one charset meta on your page. Also, why don't you use UTF-8?

Comment: I am encountering some problems with that, have a db from the previous projects.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's the solution :

**app/config/database.php :**

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_turkish_ci',
```

**head.blade.php**

```
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-9>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
```

And then you're going to encounter collation problems while having eloquent queries like :

```
$query = MyModal::where(function($query){
   $query->where('id', '=', Session::get('id'))->where('abc', '=', iconv("cp1254","UTF-8","Türkişh Characters Included"));
})->orWhere(function($query){
   $query->where('pidm', '=', Session::get('id'))->where('xyz', '=', iconv("cp1254","UTF-8","Türqüise Chars Again"));
})->orWhere(function($query){
   $query->where('pidm', '=', Session::get('id'))->where('qwe', '=', iconv("cp1254","UTF-8","ğğşşüüöö"));
})->get();
```

**Solution :**
So i used **iconv** function to create a solution. 
**Additional info :** 
Normal queries like
 `$query = MyModal::where('id', '=', Session::get('id'))->get()`
does not affect, but if there's a function in your eloquent query, you'll get an error and you should use iconv().

Thanks.